# Terraform upgrade to .12 causing issue with element

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have following code for creating an eni:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "eth0" {
  private_ips     = "10.10.0.1"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.secg1.id}"]
  subnet_id       = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.sub01.ids,0)}"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["subnet_id"]
  }
}
```

Above code stopped working in version .12, it was working in .11. 
I tried following to replace element:

```
"tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.trust-sub01.ids)[0]"
```

and:

```
"index(data.aws_subnet_ids.trust-sub01.ids)[0]"
```

both are not working it is giving me an error "The subnet ID does not exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you're not just using the [aws_subnet data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet.html). You can dial in which subnet gets returned using filters and then use the `id` attribute from that:

```
data "aws_subnet" "default" {
  vpc_id = "vpc-0dfc13e14b4e1fa57"
  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone-id"
    values = ["use1-az4"]
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "eth0" {
  private_ips = "172.31.16.1"
  subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.default.id

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["subnet_id"]
  }
}
```

If you have to use `aws_subnet_ids` like creating a network interface for each subnet you could do something like this:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "default" {
  vpc_id = "vpc-0dfc13e14b4e1fa57"
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "eth0" {
  count = length(data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids)
  subnet_id = element(tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids),count.index)

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["subnet_id"]
  }
}
```